# KTable from a topic and service restart

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I am confused so asking this question here.

1. Create a Ktable K1 from a Kafka topic T1. Read from offset 0 to offset latest.
2. Topic T1 is produced by someother service, here it is consumed only to create KTable K1
3. I restart my service
4. I understand the Ktable K1 will be recreated and my question is

Q. Will the KTable K1 have all data from topic T1 again or the table consumer will preserve the offset and ignore the already consumed messages from Topic T1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KTable K1 will have all data from topic T1.

Comment: Can you please provide the link to the documentation where it is stated? I did not manage to find this info

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/35/documentation/streams/architecture#streams_architecture_recovery